# Firebase App Script getData() optQueryParameters with integer error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm looking using a Google spreadsheet to display some data from Firebase.

How ever the data can some times be to big for Google sheets to handle.

I just wanted to limit the data to the last 10 records.

I wanted to order by `key` and then get the last 10 records.

```
var records = base.getData("path/Foo", {"limitToLast": 10 , "orderBy":"key"});
```

The problem is the documentation shows that `optQueryParameters` is supported but no where does it show how to use them. Above is the closest I have gotten. Still does not work and errors

EDIT:

So i have been keeping at it and i think i got the order sorted but not the limitToLast

```
var records = base.getData("path/Foo", { ".indexOn": "Key", ".limitToLast":"2"});
```

Has any one got the limitToLast work on app script?

EDIT2:

Here is the latest version i have used:

var records = database.getData("40274400", {"limitToLast": 1 , "orderBy":"$key"});

How ever i can't get limitToLast to work. It sends error with:
Error
limitToLast must be an integer (line 135).

Yes i know it is an integer very weird.

Comment: Try "$key" vs key.

Comment: tried that but that didn't work the real problem is the limitToLast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax to specify order-by-key is `$key`:

```
var records = database.getData("40274400", {"limitToLast": 1 , "orderBy":"$key"});
for (var key in records) {
  Logger.log(key+"="+records[key]);
}
```

This logs the value of the last child under `40274400`.

**Update**:

If you get:

> limitToLast must be an integer

You are using version 12 or earlier of the FirebaseApp library. Be sure to upgrade to [version 13](https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/1hguuh4Zx72XVC1Zldm_vTtcUUKUA6iBUOoGnJUWLfqDWx5WlOJHqYkrt/13) or later.

Comment: Excellent thx for the help. I tried that and got the bellow error. I copied your example and am sure its an int not a string. 

"limitToLast must be an integer (line 135)."

Comment: The snippet I shared is a copy/paste from a doc where it runs without errors. Are you sure you don't have other code that is causing that error?

Comment: Positive...if I get get rid of the limit it works fine

Comment: You seem to be using an older version of the FirebaseApp library. Be sure to use version 13 or later.

Comment: you hit the nail on the head I was using an old version of the library. Finally all the data is correct. you rock :)